# updated ANT propertyfile reverts on next execution

Tags: eclipse, ant

In Eclipse, I'm trying to read properties from a property file, allow user input to modify them, and then write the modified value back to the same property file.

```
    <propertyfile file="release.properties.test" comment="build version number etc">
      <entry  key="humanReadableVersion" value="1.0"/>
    </propertyfile>

    <property file="release.properties.test" />

    <input
        message="Please enter a release build identifier:"
        addproperty="humanReadableVersionFinal"
        defaultvalue="${humanReadableVersion}"
    />

    <propertyfile file="release.properties.test" comment="build version number etc">
      <entry  key="humanReadableVersion" value="${humanReadableVersionFinal}"/>
    </propertyfile>
```

The task runs fine, and the property file values update successfully. However, when re-executed, the values revert to the originals, and the file is rewritten to disk with them (I tested this by examining the contents of the file at the point in execution where the script pauses for input.

It appears that the property values are cached in memory and not reread from disk, and these cached values are rewritten to the file each time the script is rerun. I'm runnning Eclipse 3.72, ANT 1.8.2.

Comment: Did you solve this ?, I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Nope never did. Frustrating issue.